# ошибка в ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

при попытке установить изображение в ImageView приложение вылетает, если просто в xml задать картинку, то она не отображается, но как только изображение устанавливается из метода, все "крашится"
логи:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx, PID: 20649
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx.Activity_sh}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx.Activity_sh.onCreate(Activity_sh.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context="edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx.Activity_sh">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caption_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:typeface="sans"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="432dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/samovar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

метод с ошибкой:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        word = new String[]{"рыба", "рис", "самовар"};
        n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length);
        KEYPHRASE = word[n];
        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<>();
        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
        captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.рыба_caption);
        captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
        captions.put(PHONE_SEARCH, R.string.phone_caption);
        captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                .setText("Preparing the recognizer");
        //ImageButton imgBut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish);

        // Check if user has given permission to record audio
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
            return;
        }
        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task
        new SetupTask(this).execute();
    }
```

помогите пожалуйста понять, в чем дело

Comment: В разметке нет элемента ``imageView``, а есть ``imageView3``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде вы обращаетесь к несуществующему элементу разметки. В коде -

```
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

,а в разметке у вас `android:id="@+id/imageView3"`